# Slide down box menu with jQuery and CSS3 in vertical orientation

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm trying to change [this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/07/16/slide-down-box-menu/) example and do it in a vertical orientation. The problem is when I change animation the right instead of down I fail.
The 25 line is responsible for that behavior I think:

```
 .animate({'height':'+=170px'},300,
```

I've tried to change height to width, but it doesn't make sense. So [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cxveG/) is the jsfiddle example to use and see what I mean.

Comment: What is not working..?? can you be a bit more specific on what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oookay, maybe I understood what you need. You're right, first you have to change 'height' to 'width' there (line 25), and also on line 44 too!

After you need to change some css, to get the background in place.
On line 52:

```
ul.sdt_menu li span.sdt_active{
    position:absolute;
    background:#111;
    top:0px;
    width:0px;
    height:170px;
    left:170px;
    z-index:14;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cxveG/15/

Comment: Thank you, I changed my css before but only with one attribute. Therefore I have another additional question, how to change animation direction from sliding left to sliding down in a sub menu (responsible for this is line 27-32 in js file)

Comment: Here it is:
http://jsfiddle.net/cxveG/16/
Actually, you have to change the elements of the sdt_box class, switch 'left' to 'top' and 'top' to 'left'.